# Protocol for arithmetic operation implemented on another class

Tags: python, python-typing

In Python, arithmetic operations between operands of different types can be implemented on either of the operand types either using for example `__add__` for the left-hand operand, or `__radd__` for the right-hand operand. I'm trying to write a protocol that expresses that a type supports addition with a specific other type. However, for one class that I don't control, the implementation of the addition is on the right-hand operand, and so it doesn't match the protocol, even though the operation is supported. The example below illustrates this:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol


class SupportsArithmetic(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def __add__(self, other: "Delta") -> "SupportsArithmetic":
        ...


@dataclass
class Delta:
    amount: int

    def __radd__(self, other: object) -> SupportsArithmetic:
        if not isinstance(other, Instance):
            return NotImplemented
        return Instance(other.value + self.amount)


# I can't modify this class
@dataclass
class Instance:
    value: int


def add_delta(lhs: SupportsArithmetic) -> None:
    print(lhs + Delta(7))

add_delta(Instance(5))
```

The function `add_delta` works, but `mypy` complains that `Instance` doesn't implement the protocol when calling `add_delta`.

The real use-case is more complex. `Instance` is actually Python's `datetime` type, and `Delta` is `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`. So I can't modify either type. I have created a type that can be used as a drop-in for `datetime` for certain operations, such as adding a `relativedelta` to it. I now wanted to create a protocol, so that I can annotate functions that take either a `datetime`, or my custom type.

Comment: There's [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/10zdidm) which might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually very interesting and relevant. I'm guessing the answer then is that there's now good way to do this for now.

Comment: Consider that addition of `Instance`s and `Delta`s might not be commutative, so there's good reason to distinguish between `Instance(5) + Delta(7)` and `Delta(7) + Instance(5)` at this level.

Comment: @chepner Yes, but as written above, the protocol would only allow the first variant of the operation. Intuitively I'd expect this to follow the rules that Python uses when calling these operator implementations. If the lhs doesn't provide `__add__`, but the rhs provides a fitting `__radd__`, then the expression is correct. Of course these two could do different things, but I don't think that's what this mechanism is intended for.

Comment: This question may really be about how to correctly define the drop-in replacement type. Python's rules for when to invoke `__radd__` are used to define the semantics of the expression itself, not the semantics or static type of either class involved in the expression.

Comment: I would rewrite this question to be less abstract, and focus specifically on the implementation of your drop-in replacement for `datetime`. (Er, since there is already a posted answer, a new question would probably be better than changing the question in a way that invalidates the current answer.)